# Change default applications

Tags: defaults

I have somehow managed to replace the default movie player, with my FTP client. I'm not sure how that happened, but now every time I double click a movie file in Finder, my FTP client launches. 
Can someone tell me how I can go about changing the default application that launches for certain file extensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select a video file, press ⌘I, change the application under Open with, and select Change All.

[image]

You can also use [duti](http://duti.org) to configure default applications in a text file.