# Change default app

Tags: macos

I double click on a jpg file and see this -

[image]

There's a PPC-only rev of this software on my Mac, but it's on a different boot drive, a drive with older OS. The startup drive is running Yosemite and has a new version of this software. If I open the app first, all is fine, but is there any way to tell the system that this current rev is my 'main' image app?

FWIW, On a desktop MacPro 5.1, with multiple boot drives.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change default applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84136/change-default-applications)

Comment: Yes. The answer I accepted below did as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the file in Finder, choose Get Info (⌘I or right-click), then select the app you wish to use for opening such files in the ‘Open with’ section. If the app is not in the list, choose Other.

The important part is then to select **Change All**, such that all files with that file type open with the app you select. The Always Open With option when right-click → Open With only sets it for that specific file, rather than applying it to all files of that type.

[image]

Comment: This did it. I was actually expecting to see a way to say "only look to use apps on the startup drive" to the OS, but this did it. Much thanks.

Comment: @Joe The Spotlight index is used for this, so you can add the folder of apps not on your startup disk to the Spotlight privacy list to remove it.